# Django atomically limit check and increment counter for multiple tables

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have 2 models/tables Cluster and Node, and possibly more, each having a "volume_limit" and "volume_count" field/column in it.

I want to atomically check the counter against the limit in its own table and increment the counter.
To atomically check and increment for just Cluster, I would do the following

```
updated = Cluster.objects.filter(id=cluster_id,     volume_count__lt==F('volume_limit')).update(volume_count = F('volume_count')+1)
if not updated:
    raise Validation('limit reached ......')
```

If I wanted to increment both Node and Cluster, I would add the following, which would undo the cluster increment, if I cant increment the node counter. Like below

```
updated = Node.objects.filter(id=node_id, volume_count__lt==F('volume_limit')).update(volume_count = F('volume_count')+1)
if not updated:
    Cluster.objects.filter(id=cluser_id).update(volume_count = F('volume_count')-1)
    raise Validation('limit reached ......')
```

I am wondering if there is way to do both of this atomically?

Basically I want to do the following in query/update operation

1. create a query for Cluster and Node objects, and possible more objects, that all have "volume_count" and "volume_limit", that need to be simultaneously checked/incremented.
2. Check that the query translates to exactly one object for each query. i.e. the counts are within limit for each object/table. That is if I am checking Cluster and node, then the query should tranlsated to only 2 object,
3. Do a volume_count=F('volume_count')+1 for all the query results  i.e. objects/table together.

How do I do this?

Comment: [django transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/)

Comment: One Way I can see this happenning is combine the query with the OR | operation, start a atomic/transaction, do an update on the combinedquery. And then check if it resulted in N updates and if not fail the atomic operation. But I am wondering if this can be done like a query/update for a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) should solve your problem. You didn't specify your database, but on PostgreSQL with the default transaction isolation level, I believe this will work:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    n_updated = Node.objects.filter(
                    id=node_id,
                    volume_count__lt==F('volume_limit')
                ).update(volume_count=F('volume_count') + 1)
    c_updated = Cluster.objects.filter(
                    id=cluster_id,
                    volume_count__lt==F('volume_limit')
                ).update(volume_count=F('volume_count') + 1)

    if not (n_updated and c_updated):
        # trigger rollback
        raise ValidationError("Limit reached")
```

The key point is that you're targeting specific rows, and if possible updating them, which will cause other transactions to block if they are trying to update the same rows. Since it's a transaction, either both updates will succeed or none will.

Comment: Thanks. This is a correct answer. It does work. But I am specifically looking to see if its possible to do this through a Query/update operation similar to how I might do it for one counter, without using the with transaction.atomic. But also understand if such an approach would be any better than your suggested approach, using with atomic. Thanks

Comment: @SarviShanmugham: I don't think it's possible. There's no way that I know of to update multiple tables with a single SQL command. Which means that you will need to use multiple commands. Which means that you will need to use transactions. Is there any particular reason you're trying to avoid `atomic()`?